Replies to an email sent via the Gmail API from the UI don't show up when listing messages of the thread when calling users.threads.get
Scenario:
I have two accounts for this: Account A and Account B.

I have sent an email to Account B from Account A. Account A and Account B are in different Google Workspace domains. I used the Gmail API in Google Apps Script (Advanced Service) to send this email. Here is my code:

function sendAndRetrieveEmail(recipient, subject, body) {
  
  // Create the raw email content
  var emailContent = [
    'To: ' + recipient,
    'Subject: ' + subject,
    '',
    body
  ].join('\r\n');

  var raw = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(emailContent);

  // Send the email using the Gmail API
  var sentMessage = Gmail.Users.Messages.send({
    raw: raw
  }, 'me');

  return sentMessage.threadId
}



I then reply to this email as Account B, using the Gmail user interface.
Once I can see the email has been received by Account A, and that in the Gmail UI it is correctly being threaded with the original email, I use the threadId returned by my function earlier to list the messages of the thread.

Problem:

When I list the messages of the thread using the Gmail API (even just using the try this API here) then only one message appears in the response, which is the initial message send programmatically by Account A.

Question:
How can I get these emails to thread properly when I get a response? Do I need to pass a particular header or parameter when sending the initial email?
Useful links:

Message Object - Gmail API
Method: users.messages.send
Methos: users.threads.get


Would you please include the snippet of code you use to list the messages in the thread?

Have you experimented with using users.threads.list to see whether the reply is listed under a different thread id?

Also: the code that attempts to list the messages in the thread: is it being run from account A or account B?

I've reproduced your described scenario, and with this code from Account A I see both the original message and the reply: console.log(Gmail.Users.Threads.get('me',threadId).messages.map(x=>x.snippet))
